# pgadmin4 tries to connect to old port but my default port is 5432 - can't login

Tags: postgresql

i cant login to my pgadmin4 panel, I m using postgre12.
When i installed postgres i put the default port to 1111, but then
I changed the port name to default 5432. I checked the postgresql.conf file and the default port is still 5432.

Now when i go to pgadmin4, and try to login with

username - postgres

password - admin or postgres

it gives me this error:

```
 could not connect to server: Connection refused 
(0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" 
(::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 1111? could not
 connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the 
server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port 1111?
```

why is it still referring to this old port 1111?

Comment: In Pgadmin, go to server `properties` -> `connections` and change the port to `5432`

Comment: @Thirumal, thx u i deleted postgre and downloading it again lool

Comment: @Thirumal, strange but even after reinstalling postgre it still gives me same error

Comment: I guess the problem is with `PgAdmin4` configuration not in `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: @Thirumal you were right! i saw the port was '1111' in connections, i changed it to 5432 and just logged in !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `PgAdmin4 configuration`.

Go to `server properties -> connections` and change the `port` to `5432`

[image]